# math with instance variables

Tags: ruby

I have this class:

```
class Account
    attr_accessor :balance
    def initialize(balance)
            @balance = balance
    end
    def credit(amount)
            @balance += amount
    end
    def debit(amount)
            @balance -= amount
    end
end
```

Then, for example, later in the program:

```
bank_account = Account.new(200)
bank_account.debit(100)
```

If I call the debit method with the "-=" operator in it (as shown in the class above) the program fails with the following message:

```
bank2.rb:14:in `debit': undefined method `-' for "200":String (NoMethodError)
from bank2.rb:52:in `<main>'
```

But if I remove the minus sign and just make it @balance = amount, then it works. Obviously I want it to subtract, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  Can math not be done with instance variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value passed into `initialize()` is a string, rather than an integer.  Cast it to an int via `.to_i`.

```
def initialize(balance)
   # Cast the parameter to an integer, no matter what it receives
   # and the other operators will be available to it later      
   @balance = balance.to_i
end
```

Likewise, if the parameter passed to `debit()` and `credit()` is a string, cast it to an int.

```
def credit(amount)
    @balance += amount.to_i
end
def debit(amount)
    @balance -= amount.to_i
end
```

Finally, I'll add that if you plan to set `@balance` outside the `initialize()` method, it is recommended to define its setter to call `.to_i` implicitly.

```
def balance=(balance)
  @balance = balance.to_i
end
```

Note: This assumes you want and only intend to use integer values.  Use `.to_f` if you need floating point values.

Comment: Forced conversion is always a good idea because it allows you to use things that aren't numbers, but *could* be numbers if you ask nicely.

Comment: Michael - your comment that I was passing a string into initialize() made me realize where my problem is. I was using an example in my question, but the way I'm actually making a new class is from an argument (ARGV). When I run the program I type something like "ruby bank2.rb 1000" which will then make a new Account with 1000 as the balance. So my guess now is that maybe arguments are always read in as Strings and that's where my whole String problem is coming from. I was using .to_i everywhere else except in initialize(). I'll give it a try after work today.

Comment: @cliff900 Yes, ARGV always holds strings.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you did

```
bank_account = Account.new("200")
```

You should actually do

```
bank_account = Account.new(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
def credit(amount)
        @balance += amount.to_i
end
def debit(amount)
        @balance -= amount.to_i
end
```

or pass a number as the parameter (the error says that you are passing a string)

Comment: Thanks. I was actually passing the value to the debit method like this: 'code'bank_account.debit(amount.to_i)'code' which I think will work. I think I figured out my issue in the comment I left in the last answer, though.